# How can I set Accessibility Identifier for all the subviews of a view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am creating two objects of the same class in my view. Now I want to set Accessibility Identifier for both the objects which are from same class.

Example:-

```
UIView *view1 , *view2
[self addSubview:view1];
[self addSubview:view2];

if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
{
     subView.accessibilityIdentifier = @"how should I set different 
                                         identifiers for different view"; 
}
```

Comment: you can also use the tag property of the `UIView` class to differentiate two objects.

Comment: Can I use tags in UI testing?

Comment: what type of UI testing do you want? please give more details here.

Answer (score 0):

You can add by storyboard for each UIView/UIlabelView etc.
[image]